# SQLite Db is not updated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing this to update with new questions my db, but it doesn't work, the db still the same after update, I mean, I have 10 questions, then I add 2 more, after that the db still has 10 questions. What am I doing wrong?

DbHelper.java

```
public void addQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();

        for (Question question : questions) {
            insertQuestion(question);
        }
    }
```

Main.java

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this).addQuestions(questions);
```

DbHelper.java

```
private void insertQuestion(Question question) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1, question.getOption1());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2, question.getOption2());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3, question.getOption3());
        cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER, question.getAnswer());
        db.insert(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

public ArrayList<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question question = new Question();
                question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
                question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
                question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
                question.setAnswer(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER)));
                questionList.add(question);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return questionList;
    }
```

Comment: can you show us code of insertQuestion method

Comment: please edit the question and place code there

Comment: try debug.Check the size of the list.

Comment: `List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();` instantiates a new **empty** list. So `QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this).addQuestions(questions);` does not insert anything to the table.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You should add to the list a few questions and then call addQuestions().

Comment: Ok ok I got it, ty.